# How can I compute the infimum of the following non linear functional

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

[image]

I was trying to solve this problem from previous exam of functional analysis and I am stuck

Clealy $ \inf_{f \in \mathcal{M}}\phi(f) \leq 0$.(I can choose f=0) If I compute the infimum over the bigger set $L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[-1,1]$, the infimum should be $-2/5$. This follows from completing the square as follows

$\phi(f)=\int_{-1}^{1}((f(x)-x^2)^2 -x^4)dx$ and since $x^2 \in L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[-1,1]$

So I am certain that $\inf_{f \in \mathcal{M}} \phi(f) \in [-2/5,0]$
I am having a hard time narrowing it down to a number. The problem I am facing is that the set $\mathcal{M}$ clearly contains functions which are not necessarily odd. If the functions were odd I could easily conclude that the infimum was 0.

Can someone help me? Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: @user3503589 : I suggest you crop the image so that it only shows the question, just because the rest is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: As the integral of an arbitrary function can be arbitrarily big in any very small interval, I would guess, the infimum would be the same ($-\frac25$), as we can approach $x^2$ by functions from $\mathcal M$, corrigating in smaller and smaller intervals...

Comment: If the infimum is attained at $f$, then for every $g\in \mathcal{M}$ and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\phi(f + tg) - \phi(f) \geqslant 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since 
$$
\phi(f) = \int_{-1}^1 (f(x)-x^2)^2 - x^4 \, dx = \int_{-1}^1 (f(x) - x^2)^2 \, dx - \int_{-1}^1 x^4 \, dx, 
$$
you essentially want to minimize the first integral. But the first integral is the $L^2$ norm of $\|f-x^2\|$ squared. We have a nice Hilbert basis for $L^2_{\mathbb R}([-1,1])$, and the subspace of functions with zero integral perhaps decomposes nicely with respect to this basis... I haven't worked out the details, feel free to ask questions. I just thought this was too big for a comment.

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I thought about your hint but I haven't come up with a successful argument to show that the infimum is indeed $-2/5$. I was trying to prove that M in dense in $L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[-1,1]$. Clearly M is closed as it is the kernel of the linear functional 1 acting on $f \in L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[-1,1]$. But then M cannot (should not) in my opinion be dense in  $L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[-1,1]$, because if it were the M would be equal to the space itself . This means I need to construct a sequence which is arbitrarily close to $x^2$ in L^2-norm. I am stuck

Comment: @user3503589 : if you think in terms of standard linear algebra, putting one linear constraint on a vector gives you an hyperplane, so no, $M$ is not dense. In fact, the zero set of a nonzero continuous linear functional is always a proper closed subspace. You actually need to compute something here, and since the Fourier series computation decomposes over a Hilbert basis consisting of odd and even functions, it should make the task not so hard.

Comment: @Ah I do not know the fourier series decomposition of $L_{\mathbb{R}}^2[-1,1]$.:(

Comment: @user3503589 In this case, an orthonormal basis consisting of polynomials would be more convenient. You don't even need to know how they all look, you only need to know that there exists an ONB \{ p_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\} of $L^2([-1,1])$ of polynomials with $\deg p_n = n$. You only need $p_0,p_2$, and see that the $p_{2k+1}$ are odd, and the $p_{2k}$ are even.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer I'm confused by your comment, isn't a polynomial of degree $0$ a constant? Did you mean $\deg p_n = n$??

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Of course I did. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Let g be a continuous linear functional on a Banach space B.Let the norm of g be G and let the null space of g be M. If g is not zero then G has co-dimension 1 in B. From this,and from the definition of G, the absolute value of g(x) is G.d(f,M) for any f in B, where d(f,M) is the distance from f to M. So if g(f) is the integral of f from -1 to 1, then G = sqrt(2) .So for the function f(x)=x2 , we have d(f,M) = 2/(5.sqrt(2)). Combine this with Patrick Da Silva's work ,and you see that the inf in the question is -1/5.

Comment: Hi user254665, welcome to Math.SE!  You might like to take a look at [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/5531) on how to write math on this site using LaTeX.

Comment: @user254665 I think it should be g has co-dimension 1(and not G which is a positive real number)

Comment: Thank you , I assume that you are using the formula $\|\phi\|dist(x,V)=|\phi(x)|$ where $\phi=1$ and $V=\mathcal{M}$ and $x=x^2$ . And you are computing $dist(x,V)^2$. I see why $\|\phi\|=\sqrt(2)$ but I do not see that after computing  $\phi(x^2)=2/3$ we get the final  answer as $-1/5$

Comment: To user 3503589. Arithmetic error of mine in last step.Sorry.